# Update existing security group when creating new ec2 CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have ec2 instance which was created using such cfn template:

Parameters:

```
"VPCId": {
    "Type":  "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
    "Description": "The VPC Id to where this instance is being created"
}
"Subnet": {
  "Description": "Subnet to put Instance",
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
},
```

Have the following Security Group:

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enables access to instance by port 80",
        "VPCId": {
            "Ref": "VPCId"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "80",
            "ToPort": "80",
            "CidrIp": {
              "Ref": "ClientCIDR"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

And part of Instance Resource:

```
"WebServer": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    "IamInstanceProfile": "access-profile",
    "SecurityGroupIds": [
      { "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "InstanceSecurityGroup",
          "GroupId"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "SubnetId": {
      "Ref": "Subnet"
    },
```

I want to create a few another instances using another template. This instances should have access to the above instance by port 22 and connect to it in UserData.

I'm not sure how it can be organized, the one way i see is update security group using aws cli through UserData before establishing ssh connection to the first instance. How it can be organized using resources? I didn't find any information or examples regarding this. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you just make a second security group for the instances that need port 22 open?

Comment: When I create instances using second template they have random public IP each time. So, i should be able to somehow update rule for WebServer instance

Comment: Ah, I see. Simon-Pierre's answer below will do the trick. Security groups can reference other security groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `InstanceSecurityGroup` to allow access from the other instances:

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "GroupDescription": "Enables access to instance by port 80",
    "VPCId": {
        "Ref": "VPCId"
    },
    "SecurityGroupIngress": [
      {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "80",
        "ToPort": "80",
        "CidrIp": {
          "Ref": "ClientCIDR"
        }
      },
      {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "22",
        "ToPort": "22",
        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
          "Ref": "OtherInstancesSecurityGroup"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

where `OtherInstancesSecurityGroup` is a new Security Group you will assign the the other instances.

Comment: Let's i try to explain again....
I have created WebServer instance with InstanceSecurityGroup using the template which I provided. This server is permanent. And should allow connection by specific IP's.

Then I take another template and want to create another instance. During the setup need to automatically update the InstanceSecurityGroup to allow this instance connection by port 22 from IP which assigned to this second instance.

Comment: Using the strategy from my answer, you will not need to specify the IP addresses that you are allowing to communicate with your server on port 22. The `SourceSecurityGroupId ` will allow any instance that has this security group to access your server on port 22, regardless of its IP address. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-sourcesecuritygroupid

Comment: What should i specify in the other template as they have own SecurityGroups? Thanks for the help

Comment: In the other template, you must declare your `OtherInstancesSecurityGroup` (using `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`) and add this resource to the `Outputs` section. You can then refer to the `OtherInstancesSecurityGroup` from your Server template: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't create a ref for non-existing SG in the first template as it creates in the second one. Could you show an example of second template?